# excluding words from collections.counter using top ten

Tags: python, collections, counter

I want to count the frequency of words used in some documents by using:

```
Counter(word.rstrip(punctuation) for word in words).most_common(10)
```

I am unable to simply tack on a .subtract(exclusion_list) to this command where exclusion_list is a list of words i dont want. How can i get the top ten words without including the exclusion list?

Comment: Do you want to not even count the excluded words, or do you want them to be counted but excluded from the list of most common words?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> words = ('proper prefix '+'1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A '*10+' proper suffix').split()
>>> exclusion_list = '1 3 5 7 9'.split()
>>> [w for w, c in Counter(words).most_common(10) if w not in exclusion_list]
['A', '2', '4', '6', '8']
```

If you want tuples of the word matched with their counts:

```
>>> [(w, c) for w, c in Counter(words).most_common(10) if w not in exclusion_list]
[('A', 10), ('2', 10), ('4', 10), ('6', 10), ('8', 10)]
```

Another way with [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=filter#filter):

```
>>> filter(lambda wc: wc[0] not in exclusion_list, Counter(words).most_common(10))
[('A', 10), ('2', 10), ('4', 10), ('6', 10), ('8', 10)]
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the top 10 words that *aren't* in the exclusion list, then this should work:

```
Counter(word.rstrip(punctuation) for word in words if word not in exclusion_list).most_common(10)
```

Otherwise, if for some reason you want to get the top 10 words and *then* exclude words that are in the exclusion list, then this should work:

```
[w for w in Counter(word.rstrip(punctuation) for word in words).most_common(10) if w[0] not in exclusion_list]
```